# err too many redirects.this page isnt working now on django

Tags: python, django

i was trying to create a registration form html page for my django project.but i ended up in a "too many redirects error".can anyone help me with this? iam new to django. here's my code :

```
    from . import views
    from django.urls import path
    app_name = 'credentials'
    urlpatterns = [
       path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
       path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
       path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout')
   ]
```

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    firstname = request.POST['first_name']
    lastname = request.POST['last_name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    confirmpassword = request.POST['password2']

    if password == confirmpassword:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Username Taken')
            return redirect('register')
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Email Taken')
            return redirect('register')`

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, email=email,
                                        password=password)
        user.save()
        messages.info(request, 'USER REGISTERED')
        print('USER REGISTERED')

else:
    messages.info(request, 'password did not match!!')
    return redirect('credentials:register')
    return redirect('/')
return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 redirects in the 'else' path... the first creates the infinit redirect:

```
else:
    messages.info(request, 'password did not match!!')
    return redirect('credentials:register')
    return redirect('/')
```